# Facebook Ruby SDK can't pull list of campaigns

Tags: ruby, facebook

#### Which SDK version are you using?

facebookbusiness-0.15.0.0

#### What's the issue?

I am unable to pull all campaigns from an Ad Account
Steps/Sample code to reproduce the issue

1. Create a session object from an access_token
2. Pull account name from API
3. Pull campaign name from API
4. Try to pull the campaign from the ad account

[image: code]

#### Observed Results:

Tried accessing nonexisting field (campaigns) on node type (Page)
I could not pull the campaigns that belong to an ad account from the API.

#### Expected Results:

I was expecting to be able to pull all Campaigns by first pulling the ad account and then trying to fetch all campaigns.
To display I do have the rights to pull both AdAccount information & Campaign information i've pulled them individually in the screenshot.

Comment: Never used this gem but have you tried doing it the way the [Getting Started Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/business-sdk/getting-started#ruby) suggests because the way you are going about it seems to differ slightly in both form and arguments provided.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response, i have tried the original way aswel. This is returning a different error; `create_response': Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument.

I was using the way shown above as it is working for pulling a record by ID.